# How to get max and min date in Yii 2

Tags: yii2

**In my databae**

```
filed type

'import_date varchar(100)'
```

**value**

```
'max => 01-01-2016'

'min =>  31-12-2015'
```

I have code to get max and min date

```
$dateMin = Report::find()->min('import_date');// ouput 01-01-2016' => false

$dateMax = Report::find()->max('import_date');// ouput 31-12-2015' => false
```

Please help me

Thank all

Comment: You should use `DATE` or similar datatype in the database for dates. You're using `VARCHAR` which will order in alphabetical order, not date order. `0` < `3`, so the result is correct for the data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the min of the converted field in date

```
$dateMin = Report::find()->min("STR_TO_DATE(import_date,'%d-%m-%Y' ");

$dateMax = Report::find()->max("STR_TO_DATE(import_date,'%d-%m-%Y' ");
```